# Minimum distance between same characters

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to find out the minimum distance (the number of characters between them) between the two same characters. (if multiple exist return the smallest one)

For example

```
1) Input = patent
<br>
output=2 (as t and t are 2 char away)
<br>
2) Input = pattern
<br>
output=0 (t and t are next to each other)<br>
3)Input = ababdbbdhfdksl
<br>
output=0 as (b and b are consecutive)
```

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt to show us.

Comment: For small strings, simply processing each character and finding the next occurrence of that character to get their separation and then recording the lowest will be "fast enough". Tell us you have tried this and it is not good enough and perhaps we can suggest other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing is one approach that I can think of.

Assumptions:

1. There are only 26 possible characters [a-z] in the input.
2. If there are no two same characters, then we return INF.

Basic Idea:

We only need to remember the last index at which the current character was found, that would be the minimum distance corresponding to the character at that position (assuming the character doesn't appear again). We can use a variable to store a global minimum.

Approach:

1. Create an array of size 26 to store the last index of each character where it is found. Let's call the array *lastIndex*[],

   - *lastIndex*[0]: Stores the last index at which the character 'a' was found.
   - *lastIndex*[1]: Stores the last index at which the character 'b' was found.
   - *lastIndex*[25]: Stores the last index at which the character 'c' was found.
2. Initialize the elements of *lastIndex* to -1.
3. Initialize a variable *minDistance* to INF.
4. Iterate over all the elements. Let *position* represent the index correspoding to the current character in *lastIndex*. If the lastIndex[position] is not equal to -1, then compute *currentMinDistance = (idx - lastIndex[position] - 1)*. If *currentMinDistance* is less than *minDistance*, then assign *minDistance* to *currentMinDistance*. Update the *lastIndex[position]* to *idx*.
5. Return *minDistance*.

You can extend this approach to store the index of elements when you update *minDistance*.

Here is the code for the approach:

```
int getMinimumDistanceBetweenSameCharcters(const string &s){
    int lastIndex[26];
    for( int idx = 0; idx < 26 ; ++idx ){
        lastIndex[idx] = -1;
    }
    int minDistance = INT_MAX;
    for( int idx = 0; idx < s.size() ; ++idx ){
        int position = s[idx] - 97; // ASCII
        if( lastIndex[position] != -1 && (idx - lastIndex[position] - 1) < minDistance ){
            minDistance = idx - lastIndex[position] - 1;
        }
        lastIndex[position] = idx;
    }
    return minDistance;
}
```

Time Complexity - O(n), where n is the size of the string.
Space complexity - O(1), assuming there is a limited number of unique characters.

Comment: This could be made simpler, although possibly slightly slower by using an std::map instead of the array. Internally that uses a sort of hashing anyways. If this would be a task for a job application, I would recommend the map because that shows you can utilize the standard library efficiently. A professor might prefer the "manual" method with an array.

Comment: @AlexGeorg Agree. Since the question doesn't clearly mention the constraints, so I went ahead with this approach. *std::unordered_map* might be more preferable than *std::map*.

Comment: If it helped, please upvote (and possibly select as an answer).